# How to remove text between two tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such a code:

```
<input type="text">some dummy text i need to remove! <select>F.i.</select>
```

I tried to to use jQuery for this. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('div').children('select').prev().remove();
```

It deletes `input` instead of that text.

So, how to remove text which is simply between tags?

Comment: "some dummy text i need to remove!" is a text node under the parent div. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it's just simpler to use the native API when working with next nodes.

```
var select = $("div > select")[0];

select.parentNode.removeChild(select.previousSibling);
```

---

You can also make your selector a little more specific if need be.

```
var select = $("div > input + select")[0];
```

---

You could use jQuery to do the remove as well if you did this:

```
var select = $("div > input + select")[0];
$(select.previousSibling).remove();
```

which means you could do it in one line:

```
$($("div > input + select")[0].previousSibling).remove();
```

but that gets a little hard to read.